# Android: software usb emulator

Tags: java, android, endpoint, emulation, pyusb

Goal:

I would like to test a java-android communication between an android terminal and another device. This communication has to be made using USB bulk tranfers. I'm using basically what you can see here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary.html

The problem:

Hmm, well I just don't have the device yet. I found "USB/IP" as a possible solution:

[How to emulate USB devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913979/how-to-emulate-usb-devices) 
http://usbip.sourceforge.net/

which seems to work fine in some cases but I've been unable to make it work with Android...

The questions:

Is it any way to test my code using some program?

Maybe I should ask this as another question but, just in case everything goes wrong, could I use libusb and python  (pyusb) with my android device?  It seems to be difficult:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.pyusb.user/1207

Comment: I don't think libusb would help you test a program written against the Android usb host APIs. Perhaps you can pick up a comparable microcontroller eval board to use as a stand in test device.  Some embedded linux systems have USB device ports, too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't mean that I wanted to test Android APIs with libusb. I just commented it because,if I am not wrong, with USB/IP, I could test a similar python program. So, I was asking about the pyusb portability to android (I should have asked it in a different question)The evaluation board it's a great idea. But I was looking for a software solution so it could be compatible with nearly everything.I guess I'll use some modified hardware or wait for the device. Anyway, maybe I'll find (or someone will post here) some "miraculous" program that works well.