# How to use usb flash or virtual drive to act as a plug and play device?

Tags: usb, emulation

I am trying to find a way to mimic a USB device being connected without actually having it available. I am trying to develop an additional feature to software that is only fully unlocked when the USB device is connected to the computer. Because the client is unable to provide a demo device for me to use here shortly, I'd like to find a way to emulate or mimic the connectivity of the device so I can finish development. Can I do this with a flash drive perhaps? Find someway to copy the files so that when I insert the flash drive it acts as a plug and play device?

Comment: What operating system? What kind of USB device are you looking for? (Storage class, HID, something else?) What is the functionality you are trying to emulate? Just a different vendor and product ID?

Comment: I am trying to emulate a camera on a windows 7 machine on a usb flash drive (sandisk); yes; I'm just trying to emulate the vendor/ID/USB key as if the model he has were connected

Comment: Are you sure that only the PID/VID is checked, without requiring other features of the USB device? With a system emulator like QEMU, you can make your own virtual USB device with given PID/VID. If the software runs in Linux, it is easy to configure QEMU with a Live CD. Otherwise, you need to install Windows in the virtual machine first.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to go about emulating the device; I hope it's alright to ask but could you point me in the direction of a resource to help me figure it out?

Comment: This similar question [How to emulate USB devices][1] might help you. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913979/how-to-emulate-usb-devices?rq=1

Comment: Thank you! looking at it now.